# Is the phrase 'just any' separable?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

In his grammar book, Swan tells that **just any** is used in negative sentences to make the meaning [any: 'one or another - it's not important which'] clear.

I wonder if this sentence below:

> You can't take **just any** bus - you need a 4 or a 16.

can be written as

> You **just** can't take **any** bus - you need a 4 or a 16.

I've seen some people use the second form somewhere (I don't know whether they made a mistake in their sentence). Do those two have the same meaning?

If they don't, could you tell me the difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you place ***just*** depends on what you mean. With *You **just** can't take any bus* (or more naturally, *You can't **just** take any bus*, emphatic ***just*** is modifying the ***verb*** (it's not sufficient to simply take a bus), whereas with *You can't take **just** any bus* (often, [*just any old bus*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22just+any+old+bus%22)), it's modifying the ***noun*** (emphasising that it must be the right ***kind*** of bus). Sometimes native speakers can be a bit sloppy about this relaively fine distinction, since context usually makes things obvious.

Comment: FumbleFingers is right. Here's an example of a similar construction. "You can't simply swim everywhere" focusses on the _action_. "You can't swim simply everywhere" focusses on the _venue_. [In the US it's "focuses"]